# Use exit, but do not close terminal, in bash script

Tags: bash, function, exit

I have created a shell function to comfortably use desktop search tool `baloosearch`. I created it as a function for a reason.

Now, in this functions I need to use `exit` command to quit loops, `if`s or `case` conditions. The problem is, when the `exit` commands gets executed, it also kills my terminal window...

My question is, is there a way to use `exit`, but without closing the terminal window?

When using this thing as a shell script, it's okay, but I need it to be run as a BASH function...

Comment: It's hard to suggest alternatives without seeing the code in question - but typically you would `break` from loops and `return` from functions

Comment: I just found it, return exits functions, without closing the shell. I created a wrapper script/function to use baloosearch. When doing a search this function allows to change directory into the found object. To achieve this, it needs to be a function, not a script. I might publish it somewhere some time later. It may be useful for people who like baloosearch.

Answer (score 5):

After 1.5 minutes of research I can now answer myself.

The solution is to use **return** instead of exit.
This way exitting the function does not close the terminal, it leaves the shell session open.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases where you need to have exit instead of return or break, you can execute the command inside a sub-terminal. `$(cmd)` then the exit will exit the sub-terminal instead.
Keep in mind that a return value will be executed.
So maybe surround with something like `echo -e "Result from cmd:\n$(cmd)"` if you only want the output.
In general `return` should be enough though, but sometimes you don't own the script.